# Ansible. Скопировать директорию на нужный сервер, в зависимости от условия

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Только начинаю изучать Ansible.

Есть задание, имея значение blue или green, копировать директорию либо на server1 либо на server2. Я решил это дело, но чувствую что сделано топорно. Есть ли решение этой задачи с меньшим колличеством кода? Я по сути, два раза повторяю одно и тоже в коде.

Команда:

```
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-var "VAR3=blue"
```

shell> cat hosts.txt

```
[servers]

server1 ansible_host=192.168.0.2 
server2 ansible_host=192.168.0.3
```

shell> cat playbook.yml

```
---

- name: deploy to blue
  hosts: server1
  become: yes

  vars:
    source_file: /home/ubuntu/my_app
    destin_file: /home/ubuntu

  tasks:
  - name: Copy file to servers
    copy: src={{ source_file }} dest={{ destin_file }} mode=755
    when: '"{{ VAR3 }}" == "blue"'

- name: deploy to green
  hosts: server2
  become: yes

  vars:
    source_file: /home/ubuntu/my_app
    destin_file: /home/ubuntu

  tasks:
  - name: Copy file to servers
    copy: src={{ source_file }} dest={{ destin_file }} mode=755
    when: '"{{ VAR3 }}" == "green"'
```

Comment: Ну чё, не решил? Мне тоже интересно как сделать.

Comment: @donRumata Решил, ответ ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создать папку host_vars,с файлами

```
server1.yml
server2.yml
```

в каждом задать своё значение VAR3, например:

```
VAR3: "blue"
```

тогда код можно сделать таким:

```
---

- name: deploy to servers
  #группа хостов из hosts.txt
  hosts: [ servers ]
  become: yes

  #эти переменные также можно задать для каждого сервера свои в host_vars, тогда этот блок можно будет убрать.
  vars:
    source_file: /home/ubuntu/my_app
    destin_file: /home/ubuntu

  tasks:
  - name: Copy file to servers
    copy: src={{ source_file }} dest={{ destin_file }} mode=755
    when: '"{{ VAR3 }}" == "blue"'

  - name: Copy file to servers
    copy: src={{ source_file }} dest={{ destin_file }} mode=755
    when: '"{{ VAR3 }}" == "green"'
```

Запуск:
Для всей группы:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts.txt playbook.yml -l servers
```

или для выбранного хоста:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts.txt playbook.yml -l server2
```

Comment: Ну у тебя всё равно 2 одинаковые таски. С разным `when`, но действие делают одно и то же. Задача не решена, имхо.

Answer (score 1):

Решил в итоге так: Изменил в hosts.txt вместо server1, server2 стало blue, green

shell> cat hosts.txt

```
[servers]

blue ansible_host=192.168.0.2 
green ansible_host=192.168.0.3
```

В плейбуке в hosts вставил {{ VAR3 }}, и всё. Код уменьшился в 2 раза.

shell> cat playbook.yml

```
---

- name: blue-green deploy
  hosts: {{ VAR3 }}
  become: yes

  vars:
    source_file: /home/ubuntu/my_app
    destin_file: /home/ubuntu

  tasks:
  - name: Copy file to servers
    copy: src={{ source_file }} dest={{ destin_file }} mode=755
```

Comment: Стоп. А чё, можно менять `server1` на `blue`? О_о Я как-то из услвия задачи это не уловил.

Comment: Ну да, получается не ясно описал задачу.